# Cómo puedo reemplazar etiquetas html

Tags: php, html, dom

Tengo un documento HTML, con varias etiquetas `iframe` con una url de youtube

```html
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyxxx" width="560px"></iframe>
```

Usando PHP DOM, ¿cómo puedo remplazarlas por

```html
<figure>
   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyxxx">
   </iframe>
</figure>
```

o quizás no reemplazarlas, pero agregar antes del `iframe` la etiqueta `figure`?

Comment: No termino de comprender la pregunta. Si estás usando PHP para generar la página, ¿por qué no generarla directamente como quieres en lugar de tratar de manipularla después de generada?¿O es que estás leyendo recursos externos que quieres procesar?

Comment: si estoy leyendo un html y tengo que hacer esos cambios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es muy sencillo procesar HTML con [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), son las herramientas que están pensadas para eso. Cada uno de los pasos está comentado en el código:

```php
$html = '
         <body>
             <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315px" 
                     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyxxx" width="560px">
             </iframe>
             <div><p>¡Acá más texto!</p></div>
             <iframe src="https://www.otro.com/iframe" width="333px"></iframe>
         </body>';

//Convertir utf8 a ISO-8859-1
$htmlISO = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'ISO-8859-1');


//Generar el DOM
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$opcionesLibXML = LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD;
$doc->loadHTML($htmlISO, $opcionesLibXML);


//Obtener todos los iframes
$iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');

//Reemplazar c/u
foreach ($iframes as $iframeViejo) {
    //Crear un nuevo iframe y asignar el src
    $iframeNuevo = $doc->createElement('iframe');
    $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('src', $iframeViejo->getAttribute('src'));

    //Crear un nuevo figure y agregarle el nuevo iframe
    $figureNuevo = $doc->createElement('figure');
    $figureNuevo->appendChild($iframeNuevo);

    //reemplazar viejo por nuevo
    $iframeViejo->parentNode->replaceChild($figureNuevo, $iframeViejo);
}


//DOM -> string final
$resultado = $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
             //documentElement :: importante para no recibir entities
echo $resultado;
```

**Resultado**

```html
<body>
    <figure><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxyyyxxx"></iframe></figure>
    <div><p>¡Acá más texto!</p></div>
    <figure><iframe src="https://www.otro.com/iframe"></iframe></figure>
</body>
```

**Demo**

http://ideone.com/OfaNhF

Comment: gracias por la ayuda si realiza la funcion de agregar la etiqueta pero en el texto los caracteres que tienen acentos los cambia por &Atilde;&, ejemplo:
entonces qu&Atilde;&copy; mejor que hacerla t&Atilde;&ordm; misma en casa
agrege la codificacion encoding="utf-8" en el header pero aparecen igual, me podrias ayudar con eso por favor

Comment: @skycomputer2 Editado para tomar utf8 y que no devuelva entidades.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvi para hacer los cambios pero ahora sucede que si tengo varias etiquetas cambia una si y otra no, no se por que, intente ponerlo en la pagina que hiciste el demo y ahi solo cambia la primera: 
http://ideone.com/vcGsiI
me podrias ayudar con eso porfavor, muchas gracias